# How to find an angle from 2 points?

Tags: java, math

I have this method in my Java program:

```
public static float findAngle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float deltaX = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
    float deltaY = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
    return (float)(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```

I got it from googling this issue.  However, when put into practice, it splits so I only get 1-180, and after 180 it goes back to 1. How do I fix this?

Comment: Two points == line does it not? You need a third to make an angle.

Comment: @A--C, third one is (0,0) I guess

Comment: Seems that way, [`atan2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) returns the angle of a polar coordinate :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call `Math.abs`. Negative numbers and positive numbers will give different results, so you want to preserve the sign of `deltaX` and `deltaY`.

Comment: Oh, duh. I was looking at atan2(), and didn't pay any attention to the Math.abs(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static float findAngle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float deltaX = x1 - x2;
    float deltaY = y1 - y2;
    return (float)(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow; it often helps to include a short description of why your solution works.